# How can I use variables to exclude certain items and store this information in my cart in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm currently developing a Shopware 6 plugin that allows the user to exclude specific products (that has been automatically added before) from the shopping cart. I want to store this information in the cart so that the user can see that certain items have already been removed and won't add them again.

How can I use variables to store data in my cart and implement this functionality? Is there a native method in Shopware 6 to store additional information related to cart items and access it later?

Answer (score 1):

You can add extensions to the instance of `Cart`.

```php
$cart->addExtension('myValues', new ArrayStruct([
    'someKey' => true,
    'anotherKey' => 'foo',
]));

// ...

/** @var ArrayStruct $myValues */
$myValues = $cart->getExtension('myValues');
$someKey = $myValues->get('someKey');
```

[Run it here](https://shopware.foo/eUhT6ffyqM)

Answer (score 1):

There's also [LineItem](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Checkout/Cart/LineItem/LineItem.php) [`getPayloadValue`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Checkout/Cart/LineItem/LineItem.php#L213C21-L213C36) and [`setPayloadValue`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Checkout/Cart/LineItem/LineItem.php#L246C21-L246C36)