# Shopware 6.5.3.3 Session Handling

Tags: shopware6

I'm currently working on a complete rework of a Shopware 6 plugin for the new version 6.5.3.3.
Because the session service was removed in newer versions of Shopware 6, the plugin does not work anymore.

I tried to get the session via some of my event subscribers inside my plugin, but unfortunately my solution does not work with all events.
With the **CheckoutConfirmPageLoadedEvent** I can access my session like this:

```
$session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();
```

In other events like the **CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent** this solution is not possible.
What is the new workaround without the old session service to access the session out of all of my subscribers?

The documentation does not help and I couldn't get any solutions from Google or the Shopware Support.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Actually this was a change done by the underlying symfony framework:
```
Remove the session service and the SessionInterface alias, use the \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::getSession() or the new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack::getSession() methods instead
```
Refer to the symfony upgrade guide: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.4/UPGRADE-6.0.md#frameworkbundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the `request_stack`.

```xml
<service id="SwagBasicExample\Subscriber\MySubscriber">
    <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

```php
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Event\CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class MySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly RequestStack $requestStack
    ) {
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent::class => 'onOrderPlaced',
        ];
    }

    public function onOrderPlaced(CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getMainRequest();

        if (!$request || !$request->hasSession()) {
            return;
        }

        $session = $request->getSession();
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

Keep in mind though, that a missing `Request` object in the event might not be an oversight. The events may very well be dispatched in the context of a console command for example, where there simply is no request at all. Evaluate whether you can use other means to store data, e.g. as a [cart extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76810157/8556259).